# How to fix crash bug on componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet?

Tags: ios, nsarray, addressbook, nscharacterset

I am making IOS app related AddressBook.
When I called below function for get phone number which have "+" symbol, I got crash error sometimes.
Anyone know this error?
Basically I am getting error on componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet function.

```
- (NSString* ) clearedPhoneNumber:(NSString* ) dirty_number withPlus:(BOOL)plus {

    if (dirty_number == nil)
        return nil;

    NSString * in_string = plus?@"+0123456789":@"0123456789";

    NSString * phone_str = [[dirty_number componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                         [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:in_string]
                          invertedSet]] 
                        componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    // Get last 10 digits
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
    if ([phone_str length] > MAX_PHONE_LENGTH) {
        range.location = 0;
        range.length = [phone_str length] - MAX_PHONE_LENGTH;
    }

   return [phone_str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
}
```

Also here is crash report.

```
Thread 3 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1956a3270 __pthread_kill (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x19561ab18 abort (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 112
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x1956de3e4 _nano_malloc_check_clear (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 0
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x1956de550 _nano_malloc_check_clear (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 364
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x1956dd0dc nano_calloc (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 80
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x1956d195c malloc_zone_calloc (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 124
6   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x1956d18bc calloc (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 64
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x194f17c24 class_createInstance (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 80
8   CoreFoundation                      0x1836e8004 __CFAllocateObject2 (in CoreFoundation) + 24
9   CoreFoundation                      0x1835c9eac +[__NSArrayI __new:::] (in CoreFoundation) + 40
10  CoreFoundation                      0x1835c9da0 +[NSArray arrayWithObject:] (in CoreFoundation) + 56
11  Foundation                          0x1845dd528 -[NSString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:] (in Foundation) + 456
12  MyApp                               0x1001aad80 0x1000e4000 + 814464
13  MyApp                               0x1001ab434 0x1000e4000 + 816180
14  AddressBook                         0x182867198 __37-[ABTCC accessRequestWithCompletion:]_block_invoke (in AddressBook) + 48
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x19555d994 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib) + 24
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x19555d954 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib) + 16
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x19556a780 _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib) + 1848
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x19556bc4c _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib) + 108
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x19573d22c _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 816
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x19573cef0 start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
```

Here is the code which called clearedPhoneNumber function.

```
- (NSMutableArray *) Get_Phones_By_Person:(ABRecordRef)person localized:(BOOL)isLocalized {

ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

if (phones == nil)
    return nil;

NSMutableArray * all_phones = [NSMutableArray array];

for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++) {
    CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j);
    NSString*  stripped_phone = [self clearedPhoneNumber:(__bridge NSString *)phoneNumberRef withPlus:YES];

    stripped_phone = [self getInternationalPhoneNumber:stripped_phone];
    if (stripped_phone != nil) {
        if (!isLocalized)
            [all_phones addObject:stripped_phone];
        else {
            CFStringRef locLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, j);
            NSMutableDictionary * dict;
            if (locLabel != nil) {
                NSString* phoneLabel =(NSString*) CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locLabel));
                dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge NSString *)phoneNumberRef, @"number", phoneLabel, @"name", nil];
                CFRelease(locLabel);
            }
            else {
                dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge NSString *)phoneNumberRef, @"number", nil];
            }

            [all_phones addObject:dict];
        }
    }

    CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
}     

CFRelease(phones);

return all_phones;

}
```

Comment: When I used above code, I can see correct phone number what I want, My problem is crash bug, sometimes there is crash bug.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is with `dirty_number` and not the character set? Update your question with the code used to obtain the value you pass to the `dirty_number` parameter.

Comment: OT: Welcome to the club, @rmaddy !

Comment: Thanks  rmaddy, I have updated dirty_number's value

Comment: @JamesChan You misunderstood. Provide your code showing how you obtain the value that you pass to the `dirty_number` parameter.

Comment: sorry, updated my question with detailed code

Comment: `(__bridge NSString )`? Really? _Really_?

Comment: You seem to be missing the asterisk anywhere you have `NSString`. That code won't even compile.

Comment: should I remove (__bridge NSString ) ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, When I did copy/paste my code, it has been removed asterisk(*), Changed code,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used addressbook in two modules.
I have removed addressbook from linphone module.
so disappear this crash error.
Please see below link.

[Crash report when user accesses the address book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514308/crash-report-when-user-accesses-the-address-book)

Thank you